# Why is my function not updating the text while using @State?

Tags: swiftui, switch-statement

For my senior capstone, I’ve basically tried to teach myself SwiftUI and create an app of a text game I thought of. I’ve had lots of issues that I persevered through up until this point, but this one is really rattling my brain. I’m trying to get the text to update when I hit the button. I really don't know how to fix this as I'm very new to SwiftUI. Does anyone know of anything that can help? I'd appreciate any help I can get. Here's my code I'm working with for this:

```
struct descriptions { 
  @State var page: Int = 0 
  func switchDesc() -> String { 
      switch page { 
         case 0: 
            return [game text] 
         case 1: 
            return [game text] 
         case 2: 
            return [game text] 
         default: 
            return "" 
    } 
  } 
}

struct GameView: View { 
    // [other variables]
    @Binding var page: Int 
    @State var desc: String = descriptions().switchDesc()
    var body: some View { 
        [...] 
        HStack { 
            Button(
                action: { 
                    page -= 1 
                    desc = descriptions().switchDesc() 
                }, 
                label: { 
                    Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.left.circle.fill") 
                }
            )
           Spacer()
           Button(
            action: {
                page += 1
                desc = descriptions().switchDesc() 
            },
            label: {
                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.right.circle.fill")}
            )
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@State` variable needs to be in the `View` for it to function like you expect it to. Also, You don't need a separate `@State` variable for the description. Instead, you can update just the `page` and then have your `switchDesc` return the correct value based on the current `page`.

For example:

```
struct GameView: View {
    @State var page: Int = 0
    
    func switchDesc() -> String {
        switch page {
        case 0:
            return "Text1"
        case 1:
            return "Text2"
        case 2:
            return "Text3"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(switchDesc())
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                page -= 1
            }) {
                Image(systemName:"arrowtriangle.left.circle.fill")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                page += 1
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.right.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your original code, you had `page` as a `@Binding` -- you alter my example to be the same thing. I just made it `@State` because right now (without seeing any other code), it seems like it would be owned by this view. Either way, the description will update correctly based on the state of that `page` variable.

---

Update, based on comments:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var page = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GameView(page: $page)
    }
}

struct GameView: View {
    @Binding var page: Int
    //etc
```

Comment: I tried it your way, really hoping it would work, but kept `page` as `@Binding` due to having to refer to the whole `GameView` view in a different view and I can't seem to figure out how to code it when it has to refer to itself for the variable.<br/> `GameView(dex: $dex, str: $str, con: $con, cha: $cha, int: $int, wis: $wis, hp: $hp, paused: $paused, page: $page)` and I have `page` as `@State` in the view this is under.

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means... I just updated with what it would look like with a `Binding` and my code still works for me. If it doesn't work for you, can you update your original question (code in comments doesn't work well) and add your version of my code and mark where you're having trouble?

Comment: I tried to edit my comment to fix things but it ended up working somehow, even though it was giving me issues less than a minute ago. But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can mark it as correct/accepted by clicking the green checkmark.